# Android tools for unzipping corrupt zip files

Tags: android, file-management, file-compression, zip

I had searched for some tools that can unzip files from a large corrupt zip file on android.

I couldn't, so now I learned how to use `ZipInputStream` in java.

Now I want to share the fruit of my tiny work.

Or if you have any other tools in your mind, please recommend me and I'll accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to program a lightweight corrupt-zip-archive extractor on Android.

[Downloadable App Release at GitHub](https://github.com/KYHSGeekCode/Unzip-Corrupt/releases)

[Source at GitHub](https://github.com/KYHSGeekCode/Unzip-Corrupt)

Hope this helps others who encounters the problem I faced.